# android how to finish an activity from other activity

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app i have 3 activities.

From 1st activity it goes to 2nd and from 2nd it goes to 3rd.  From 3rd it is coming to 1st again. and if I press back key from the 1st then it should go to home screen (App will stop).
If I press back key of 1st its goes to 2nd activity again and if I press 2nd's back key, then it goes to the 1st . Then if I press back key of 1st then app stops.

What I want , when I am in 3rd activity and press the back button then it should go to 1st and simultaneously finish the 2nd activity.

How can I do that?

Comment: Make sure you're calling super.finish() in your finish() functions.

Comment: finish()? how to write finish(). If i ll write then same activity ll finish na?

Comment: If you don't already have finish() functions, then don't worry; my suggestion won't solve your problem.

Comment: Here is a great answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10379507/478162

Answer (score 17, accepted):

just finish the second activity when you open third activity

suppose in second activity on some button click you are opening third activity using start activity;

```
startActivity(intent);
finish();//this will finish second activity and open third activity so when you press back from third activity it will open first activity.
```

if you want depended on some condition then on activity

```
setResult(123);
```

something code like this

now when override onActivityResult in second activity

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==123){
            //finish
        }
    }
```

also make sure one thing you need to use startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode); for result in second activity to start third activity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Activity2 extends Activity{

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(new Intent(Activity2.this,Activity3.class)), 12);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(resultCode==123 && requestCode==12){
            finish();
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Activity3 extends Activity{

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setResult(123);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont want that. I want to finish 2nd activity for particular condition happen within 3rd activity.

Comment: Within which activity i should write this?

Comment: Bcz i want to start 1st activity and at the same time i want to finish 2nd activity  from the 3rd.

Comment: check code it should be like this in 3 rd activity you can set different result code for different conditions.

Comment: I did like this but no effect.

Answer (score 4):

When you start your third activity you should call in your 2nd acitivity like this:

`startActivityForResult(intent, 0)`

When you finish your 3rd activity, you should include:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

It sends a signal from the 3rd activity to the 2nd.

In the 2nd put:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     finish();
}
```

It receives this signal and finishes the 2nd activity.

Comment: how to set result? I am not getting

Answer (score 2):

You should launch the 1st activity in 3rd activity with the cleartop flag when you need to finish the 2nd activity.

```
class ThirdActivity extends Activity {
    ....
    if (somecondition) { 
         /* directly go to FirstActivity, finish all intermediate ones.*/
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.Class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        finish(); // to simply return to 2nd activity.
    }
    .....
    ....
 }
```

Comment: but is this gonna finish thee 2nd activity ?

Comment: Why do you need to keep the 2nd activity alive until 3rd activity is finished?

Comment: Do you call finish just after launching 3rd activity? Where are you calling `finish`?I think u are do it in 3rd activity now.thats why 3rd activity is exiting.

Comment: actualy i am working with server. so for some particular condition only the 2nd activity ll finish. Not for every time.

Comment: then you should use @beni ansnwer.

Comment: when i am starting 1st activity from 3rd at that time only 2nd activity ll finish.

Comment: Use `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` while launching the 1st activity from 3rd.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: Didi it work? I suggested a cleaner method.. check out. Definite improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could set an intent flag called `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` on the 2nd Activity.  This way it is not kept in the history stack so when you navigate back from the 3rd activity it will go straight to the 1st.

E.g.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.Class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

This means that when you launch an activity from the `SecondActivity` the `SecondActivity` will be finished automatically.

Comment: but i donot want that every time 2nd activity ll finish . I want for some particular condition

Comment: that means when control comes from 3rd activity to 1st at time it should finish the 2nd.

Answer (score 1):

Using this way: In your first activity, declare one Activity object like this,

```
public static Activity fa;
onCreate()
{
    fa = this;
}
```

now use that object in another Activity to finish first-activity like this,

```
onCreate()
{
    FirstActivity.fa.finish();
}
```

More information : [Finish an activity from another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379134/finish-an-activity-from-another-activity)