# Creating an Android search result list

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, listactivity

I am trying to implement the following logic:

**User enters a search string in a text box (an activity) -> Web service is called to perform the search asynchronously -> Search results are displayed in a list (another activity)**

So far I have the following:

An **activity to enter the search string and click a "Search" button**:

```
public class Search extends Activity
{
    // ...
    // called when "Search" button is clicked
    private void runSearch()
    {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
            this, "Search", "Search...");
        searchAsyncTask = new SearchAsyncTask();

        SearchAsyncTaskParam param = new SearchAsyncTaskParam();
        param.SearchString = getSearchCode(); // gets input from text box
        param.ProgressDialog = progressDialog;

        searchAsyncTask.execute(param);
    }
}
```

Then I have a **class to perform the asynchronous search**:

```
public class SearchAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<SearchAsyncTaskParam,
    Void, SearchAsyncTaskResult> {

    private SearchAsyncTaskParam param;

    @Override
    protected SearchAsyncTaskResult doInBackground(
        SearchAsyncTaskParam... params) {
        if (params.length > 0)
            param = params[0];
        SearchAsyncTaskResult result = new SearchAsyncTaskResult();

        // call Webservice and fill result object with status (success/failed)
        // and a list of hits (each hit contains name, city, etc.)

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(SearchAsyncTaskResult result) {
        param.ProgressDialog.dismiss();
        if (!result.Success)
            // throw an AlertBox
        else
        {
            // this part is incomplete and doesn't look good, does it?
            // And how would I pass my result data to the new activity?
            Intent intent = new Intent(param.ProgressDialog.getContext(),
                SearchResultList.class);
            param.ProgressDialog.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

And the last element is an **activity to display a list with the search results**:

```
public class SearchResultList extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data));
        // String was only for testing, should be a class with holds the data
        // for each item, i.e. Name, City, etc. And where do I get "data" from?
    }
    // ...
}
```

Now my **questions**:

1. Is it a good idea to start the activity for the result list in the `onPostExecute` method of the `AsyncTask` instance? I have tested it with the simple test sketched above and it seems to work. But is this safe, am I on the right thread (UI thread) at all? If this is bad practice what is the alternative to start the result activity?
2. It looks especially weird to use the context of the `ProgressDialog` for the `Intent` and to start the activity. It is just the only context I have available in the `AsyncTask` instance. Can this be a problem because the `ProgressDialog` is already dismissed? What context else could I use?
3. How do I pass my result data into the `SearchResultList` activity?
4. In case of a successful search (the `else` case in the `onPostExecute` method above) I would like to close the `Search` activity with the text box so that, if the back button is hit, the user returns to the main screen (which the search activity was opened from) and not the `Search` activity. Is this possible and how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, because you are on the UI thread. The alternative would be if you aren't using AsyncTask but just a simple thread. In that case you would use a Handler to notify the UI thread that work is complete. This is one of the reasons Asynctask exists, so you don't have to do the latter version.
2. > "It looks especially weird to use the context of the ProgressDialog
   >   for the Intent and to start the activity."

   It's not weird at all because when you created the ProgressDialog you passed the context of Search, so when you retrieve the context of the ProgressDialog you actually get the context of the Search activity. No problem at all.
3. This depends on what data you want to pass. If you just want to pass an array of Strings you could do it like this:

   ```
   String [] data = getData();
   Intent intent = new Intent(param.ProgressDialog.getContext(),
       SearchResultList.class);
   intent.putExtra("key1", data);
   param.ProgressDialog.getContext().startActivity(intent);
   ```

   Then in the SearchResultList activity you would do:

   ```
   String [] data = this.getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("key1");
   ```

   If you would like to pass an object of your own, see this question: [How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)
4. Is it possible? Yes. There's two ways to do this in your case. Either you can, as I would do it,  write the SearchAsyncTask as a inner class in your Search class and the just call

   ```
   Search.this.finish();
   ```

   If some condition holds, or you can check out the accepted anwser to this question: [android how to finish an activity from other activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511216/android-how-to-finish-an-activity-from-other-activity)

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, great help! (I have formatted your answer a bit.) About point 3 I am unsure. It's not possible to pass an array of objects into `putExtra`, only primitive types? Did I understand that correctly? The answer to the question you linked looked a bit overkill for my purpose because I do not actually want to maintain a global state (in the application instance) but just pass some temporary data into the activity. Is there no other way?

Comment: Glad I can help! Only primitive types(and strings), yes. There is one more way to do it, but it's a bit dangerous: You can declare your data object as static and access it directly from SearchResultList by doing SearchAsyncTast.myObject. It's dangerous because you might cause a memory leak.

Comment: I am just studying this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents/2141166#2141166 There seems to be an overload for `putExtra` which takes a `Parcelable` (and another one which takes a `Bundle`). Will take a closer look if I can leverage this. At first glance it seems like this is what I am looking for, doesn't it?

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't know that. Yes it will solve your problem, but in terms of overkill, the first option is probably less overkill =)