# Finish an activity from another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to finish one activity from another activity, like:

In Activity [A], on button click, I am calling Activity [B] without finishing Activity [A].

Now in Activity [B], there are two buttons, **New** and **Modify**. When the user clicks on modify then pop an activity [A] from the stack with all the options ticked..

But when the user click on **New** button from Activity [B], then I will have to finish Activity [A] from the stack and reload that Activity [A] again into the stack.

I am trying it, but I am not able to finish Activity [A] from the stack... How can I do it?

I am using the code as:

From Activity [A]:

```
Intent GotoB = new Intent(A.this,B.class);
startActivityForResult(GotoB,1);
```

Another method in same activity

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    if (requestCode == 1)
    {
        if (resultCode == 1) {
            Intent i = getIntent();
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            finish();

            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

And in Activity [B], on button click:

```
setResult(1);
finish();
```

Comment: hey, you wanted to finish one activity from another right... then I had posted the answer which is correct. But, why did you vote it down ?

Comment: There is a thread with a few nice answers here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355731/killing-one-activity-from-another/16438596#16438596

Comment: Please see this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/72124506/12272687

Answer (score 200, accepted):

1. Make your activity A in manifest file: `launchMode = "singleInstance"`
2. When the user clicks new, do `FirstActivity.fa.finish();` and call the new Intent.
3. When the user clicks modify, call the new Intent or simply finish activity B.

**FIRST WAY**

In your first activity, declare one `Activity object` like this,

```
public static Activity fa;
onCreate()
{
    fa = this;
}
```

now use that object in another `Activity` to finish first-activity like this,

```
onCreate()
{
    FirstActivity.fa.finish();
}
```

**SECOND WAY**

While calling your activity `FirstActivity` which you want to finish as soon as you move on,
You can add flag while calling `FirstActivity`

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

But using this flag the activity will get finished evenif you want it not to. and sometime `onBack` if you want to show the `FirstActivity` you will have to call it using intent.

Comment: You are holding a static reference to an activity. This will never go away unless you clear it manually from somewhere -> you are creating a memory leak!

Comment: Plus for declaring an activity singleInstance is also not a good practice. This is recommended approach only for Launcher type apps. "singleTop" should be used instead.

Comment: It will remove the top activities, which i believe is what @Kanika is asking for. if not he can just use the single Top flag. this will bring the old one to top and wont close the old ones but won't create a new instance, it will just rearange the activity stack. I agree that you answer provides an alternative but it requires a cleanup code afterwards which just complicates things.

Comment: If you think there can be any changes in my answer that can improve performance and coding style..then please copy my answer..make changes..and post as another answer..and I will surely Upvote and Appreciate it.

Comment: Well its ok, you have my +1 for out-of-the-box thinking :D, i would just change to singleTop. however it still won't be my first choice when doing something similar. by cleanup code i meant a way to get rid of the static reference so there is no memory leaking, but that depends on the app structure.

Comment: is it possible without using without using launchMode = "singleInstance".

Comment: Please no one use the first solution, it is completely wrong. You are bypassing the Android framework in a really hacky way whilst creating a zombie object. Use a BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: @S-K' I only see your comments in this thread no any answer, please put your answer too and that would be much help full to all of us.

Comment: Awesome solutions. Worked very well for my problem in which I was going from activities A->B->C and on onBackPressed of C, I was launching new instance of B. But then if I did onBackPressed on that new instance of B, it used to go to the old instance of B instead of old instance of A (what I wanted). So I followed your first method in the onBackPressed of C, and it gave me the behaviour I wanted :) Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @Darko About the leak issue you mentioned on the 1st way, if on_Destroy we make the fa = null, then wouldn't the garbage collector delete it from the ram?

Comment: @Darko: You are right. User should take care of the variabe and Null it in case some other method tries to use it.

Comment: Accepted but wrong answer. As commented above, this will create a memory leak.

Comment: Work like a charm;)

Comment: In Kotlin I just did FooActivity.me?.finish() and FooActivity.me = null to avoid the leak.

Comment: The first works, but sometime it happens [Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Activity.finish()' on a null object reference] on FirstActivity.fa.finish();

why?

Comment: This is a terrible answer. First part holds a static reference to an activity wich is a bad practice. Second part does not finish activityA, it creates a new instance of activityA with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY.

Answer (score 115):

That you can do, but I think you should not break the normal flow of activity. If you want to finish you activity then you can simply send a broadcast from your activity B to activity A.

Create a broadcast receiver before starting your activity B:

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals("finish_activity")) {
            finish();
            // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT.
        }
    }
};
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("finish_activity"));
```

Send broadcast from activity B to activity A when you want to finish activity A from B

```
Intent intent = new Intent("finish_activity");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

I hope it will work for you...

Comment: It shows this error "Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead" on "registerReceiver(broadcast_reciever, new IntentFilter("finish_activity"));".

What's wrong?

Comment: "you should not break the normal flow of activity" +1 for this

Comment: Don't forget to unregister `broadcast_receiver` with `unregisterReceiver()`

Comment: [Obviously not working if you turn Dev Options->Don't Keep Activities because this solution break normal flow](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/3599baab8dd9dbf50f283dd3bfe4fdfd)

Comment: This is the solution. nice one

Answer (score 21):

This is a fairly standard communication question. One approach would be to use a ResultReceiver in Activity A:

```
Intent GotoB=new Intent(A.this,B.class);
GotoB.putExtra("finisher", new ResultReceiver(null) {
    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        A.this.finish();
    }
});
startActivityForResult(GotoB,1);
```

and then in Activity B you can just finish it on demand like so:

```
((ResultReceiver)getIntent().getExtra("finisher")).send(1, new Bundle());
```

Try something like that.

Comment: +1 just , ((ResultReceiver)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("finisher")).send(1, new Bundle());

Answer (score 12):

There is one approach that you can use in your case.

Step1: Start Activity B from Activity A

```
startActivity(new Intent(A.this, B.class));
```

Step2: If the user clicks on modify button start Activity A using the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`.Also, pass the flag in extra.

```
Intent i = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.putExtra("flag", "modify");
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Step3: If the user clicks on Add button start Activity A using the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`.Also, pass the flag in extra. `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` will clear all the opened activities up to the target and restart if no launch mode is defined in the target activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.putExtra("flag", "add");
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Step4: Now `onCreate()` method of the Activity A, need to retrieve that flag.

```
String flag = getIntent().getStringExtra("flag");
if(flag.equals("add")) {
    //Write a code for add
}else {
    //Write a code for modifying
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Start your activity with request code :

```
StartActivityForResult(intent,1234);
```

And you can close it from any other activity like this :

```
finishActivity(1234);
```

Comment: In what language??

Comment: 'startActivityForResult(Intent!, Int): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

Answer (score 5):

See [my answer to Stack Overflow question *Finish All previous activities*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330260/finish-all-previous-activities/6330456#6330456).

What you need is to add the `Intent.FLAG_CLEAR_TOP`. This flag makes sure that all activities above the targeted activity in the stack are finished and that one is shown.

Another thing that you need is the `SINGLE_TOP` flag. With this one you prevent Android from creating a new activity if there is one already created in the stack.

Just be wary that if the activity was already created, the intent with these flags will be delivered in the method called `onNewIntent(intent)` (you need to overload it to handle it) in the target activity.

Then in `onNewIntent` you have a method called restart or something that will call `finish()` and launch a new intent toward itself, or have a `repopulate()` method that will set the new data. I prefer the second approach, it is less expensive and you can always extract the 
`onCreate` logic into a separate method that you can call for populate.

Answer (score 5):

I've just applied Nepster's solution and works like a charm. There is a minor modification to run it from a Fragment.

To your Fragment

```
// sending intent to onNewIntent() of MainActivity
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("transparent_nav_changed", true);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

And to your OnNewIntent() of the Activity you would like to restart.

```
// recreate activity when transparent_nav was just changed
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("transparent_nav_changed", false)) {
    finish(); // finish and create a new Instance
    Intent restarter = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(restarter);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think i have the easiest approach... on pressing new in B..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
intent.putExtra("NewClicked", true);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in A get it

```
  if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("NewClicked", false)) {
        finish();// finish yourself and make a create a new Instance of yours.
      Intent intent = new Intent(A.this,A.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, a few of these methods didn't work for me so for anyone looking in the future or having my troubles this worked for me

I overrode `onPause` and called `finish()` inside that method.

Answer (score -3):

First call `startactivity()` then use `finish()`