# Killing one activity from another

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two activities A and B. B is a transparent pass through activity, and A is seen. I want to kill B by pressing a button A.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
B obj=new B();
obj.finish();
```

I created an object of B and tried to kill it. That didn't work.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("keep", true);
                startActivity(intent);
```

What this code is supposed to do is clear the top most activity, which is B and call B again, except this time I'm passing a value such that B kills itself after a few seconds.

This only piled up more instances of the activity for some reason. Or at least I think that's what happened because the screen became pixelated due to many transparent activities.

Here's my manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.xxx.xxx.B"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" >
    </activity>
```

What do I have to do so that, when I hit a button once the activity is displayed and the second time kills it? The creation part is obviously taken care of. My activity B pops up, I want to kill it now that B is on top.

**EDIT**

I tried this with a checkBox, here's the code:

```
enable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finishActivity(0);
            Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
            if (enable.isChecked()) {
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("keep", true);
                intent.putExtra("value", 10);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("keep", false);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        }
    });
```

When enable is checked the activity is called, which works fine. But they keep piling on. It's not like this A->B->A->B when I check and uncheck the checkBox. It's A->B->BB->BBB

Comment: oh yeah! got the same problem...

Comment: Your question is not clear. A launches B which is transparent. And do you want to stop B by clicking a button from A when B is on top?

Comment: @gezdy Yeah, that's what I want to do.

Comment: @gezdy No it isn't. I can use A as it is. I just need to find a way to close B. Please try it out before posting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finish an activity from another activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379134/finish-an-activity-from-another-activity)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You could try to directly kill an activity by calling a static method in that activity:

Activity A should have a variable

```
 static ActivityA activityA;
```

In onCreate state:

```
 activityA = this;
```

and add this method:

```
public static ActivityA getInstance(){
   return   activityA;
 }
```

In activity B, call the function getInstance()

```
ActivityA.getInstance().finish();
```

Comment: I want it to kill the app only if the checkBox is disabled. Isn't there a way to just pass a variable without using intents?

Comment: Yes, use the above getInstance, then you can access any public variable and method in the activityA. In activity B, state ActivityA activityA = ActivityA.getInstance(); Then simply check your box by if(activityA.checkBox){....}

Comment: When you close ActivtyA, kill the reference to it in Activity B: activityA = null;

Comment: I understand why the null pointer exception arises. The activity hadn't been called yet.

Comment: I don't think so, but it is a way to access public items of another class, which includes Activity, which still only a class. Another way to share varibales is to create a static varibales in a separate class, then all activities can use it.

Comment: Yes, you can check if the instance is null first

Comment: This is just a singleton approach...Not helpful

Comment: Nice, Really simple . TX

Comment: You should strictly avoid declaring android context objects (such as activity) as static because memory leaks could occur.

Comment: make static ActivityA activityA -> public  static ActivityA activityA

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice way to finish one activity from another, it is similar to what Lumis did.
So if you want to close ActivityA from ActivityB you can do this:

In ActivityA do:

```
className = this.getClass().getName();
```

and pass it on to AvtivityB. Then in ActivityB do:

```
((Activity) Class.forName(className).newInstance()).finish();
```

You can put a string with the name of your class into className yourself, but it needs to be a full name with package too.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work and I fail to understand how this could work. The code basically creates a new activity object and then calls finish on it. However, this object is not the activity object stored in the stack. Thus, the activity in the stack stays there.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, the clearer approach is create a local broadcast, in this way no memory leak or null problem. Actually this is the exact and proficient  way for passing data to previous activity. First, create a reciever in Activity_A and register it on resume and uregister it on destroy. In Activi_A (in my case Bg_show Class)  :

```
 BroadcastReceiver bgshowBroacast = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String extra = intent.getStringExtra("BROADCAST");
            if (extra != null) {
                if (extra.equalsIgnoreCase("finishBgShowActivity")) {

                    finish();
                    Log.i(TAG, "onReceive: Bg_show_BroadCast receive from bg_send class ");
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).registerReceiver(bgshowBroacast, new IntentFilter("BG_SHOW_BROADCAST"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).unregisterReceiver(bgshowBroacast);
    }
```

Then in Activity_B (in my case Bg_send Class) :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("BG_SHOW_BROADCAST");
                        intent.putExtra("BROADCAST", "finishBgShowActivity");
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext)
                                .sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Thus the previous activity will finish where the receiver registered.

Happy coding.... .

Answer (score -1):

Create static  Class variable to save the instance:
    static SampleActivity sampleActivity;

On Create of first Activity save the Instance, like this:
        incidenteActivity = this;

Create a static method to get the instance:

```
public static SampleActivity getInstance(){
    return   sampleActivity;
}
```

wherever you want call:

```
SampleActivity.getInstance().finish();
```

it really works,
regards,

Comment: Thank you @Joilson. But, what's the difference between already accepted answer (by @Lumis) and your answer.