# Automatically closing of an Android app with help of an Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, undefined-behavior, exit-code

I have Made a Simple Beginner Application with the help of Drawables and Intent. The Idea is making four activities and using Thread move from one to other Activities and when it reaches to the last activity, i want to close the Application Automatically, popping up a toast as "BYE" or something else.
If it is possible by Intent or any other way do guide me.

**Code of my Last Activity is below, but it loops to the Last activity to Infinity:**

```
package mj.manan.thisisit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ScreenLast extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screenlast);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(){
            public void run(){

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    finish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                     Intent innt = new Intent(ScreenLast.this,ScreenLast.class);
                     innt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                     startActivity(innt);
                     ScreenLast.this.finish();

                }
            }
        };
        t1.start();

 }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To **Quit** Application by `intent` use this code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
```

Try it.

Comment: that doesnt quit an app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130493/how-to-close-android-app-completely/21130567#21130567

Comment: doesnt quit app. did you read what you posted? still in background

Answer (score 0):

There can be different approaches. I think you can use broadcast sender and receiver also for you case. Similar answer I posted once it may help you.

[Finish an activity from another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379134/finish-an-activity-from-another-activity/10379275#10379275)

Answer (score 0):

If what I understood is Correct you want to kill end your activity when the Activity stack is not empty or to be more precise there is more than one activity in the stack.

Ill show you how I did it and you can tweak it as you like

when you reach the point you want to close activity do this:

```
                   Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Main.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

then in onCreate you add :

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
            finish();
        }
```

you can add toast to second part or add timer or whatever youd like.
the point is, first we clear all the Activity stack leaving only our current... then we finish it.

Comment: It made a loop and didn't exits the App.

Comment: explain to me how could it make a loop if you clear all the stack?...so read the code... understand it and use it... i use it all the time... IT WORKS IN MY APPS ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample code to quit an application

```
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        intent1.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                        startActivity(intent1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling your same Activity :- `Intent innt = new Intent(ScreenLast.this,ScreenLast.class);`

either call other activity instead of this.

Or

You can also use handler for this-

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screenlast);
        Toast.makeText(ScreenLast.this, "Bye", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        move_next();
        }

public void move_next()
{
final Handler handle = new Handler();
        Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
            public void run() 
            {               
                finish();
            }
        };
        handle.postDelayed(delay,2000);
}
```

Comment: I just want to exit from the app, not Rpeat it

Comment: if you want to run that activity once then you have to call finish(); and remove all contents form finally.

Comment: Try code with handler. And in your other 3 activities when you call next activity i.e Intent i = new Intent(this, next.class); startActivity(i); just add finish(); after this code.