# Android clear all webView and activity history whatsoever

Tags: android, webview, history, onbackpressed

I have MAIN Activity and WEB activity with webView. MAIN always performs some processing and redirects automatically to WEB.

When on WEB I enter Preferences, make preference changes and when I press Back I return to WEB.
However, in preferences I can also preform an account deletion and that will perform account deletion and start MAIN which again will start WEB automatically but this time, since the account was deleted, in a different webView (registration).

PROBLEM:
When on registration after account deletion, if I press Back I return to my (deleted) account, meaning to the webView from which I have entered preferences to delete the account.

In the preferences Fragment, if account delete, I start MAIN with Intent and add the followings:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
getActivity().finish();
```

but it doesn't help.

I have also tried clearing webView cache and history and it doesn't help either.

I have considered adding

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

to the manifest but as I said, when I just change preferences I still want to be able to return to previous activity.

Any ideas what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

OK.
found a solution in here:
[Finish an activity from another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379134/finish-an-activity-from-another-activity)

However, I still need to check the implications of using

```
launchMode = "singleInstance"
```

in the Manifest.

For now it's good, if someone else have a different solution, will be happy to hear about it.