# I want to finish activity from other activity

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

There are three activities: A, B, C;

A, B are normal activities, C is transparent activity to show a kind of guide.

I programmed when I go B from A, C starts automatically on B.

The problem is when I instantly press back button at when B starts,

C shows up on A.

I want to solve this problem, please help.

Comment: This is already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379134/finish-an-activity-from-another-activity

Answer (score -1):

You could inside activity B

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     // Here finish activity C
     super.onBackPressed();
}
```

**Other solution**: Keep a public reference to Activity C

1. In the manifest.xml set Activity C `launchMode = "singleInstance"`
2. Inside Activity C:

```
public static Activity activity;
onCreate(){
    activity = this;
}
```

3. Finish it from any activity:

```
if(ActivityC.activity != null) {
    ActivityC.activity.finish();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I will try this right now and tell you the result!

Comment: I think i need to consider another solution, not finishing activity, maybe preventing back pressing