# Create new Instance Of activity by Intent every time android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

How to prevent to create every time Instance of Store activity?

When I call `startActivity(new Intent(this,StoreActivity.class))`, it will create new instance and call `OnCreate` Method in `StoreActivity`. I want to call one time `Oncreate`.

Is this Possible ?

Comment: Not possible. You should look at this documentation http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html and use similar concepts to save the activity state (when your activity is destroyed) and then reuse those saved states when you recreate the activity from an intent.

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
startActivity(new Intent(
       this,StoreActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP));
```

From [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)

```
public static final int FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
```

*If set, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack.*

Constant Value: 536870912 (0x20000000)

Comment: What do you mean by its not working? Is it still launching new instance even if activity is open?

Comment: when i call storeActivity from MainActivity , OnCreate Method call during create instance of StoreActivity , Now i pressed back , onBackpressMethod call from Storeactivity ... and i am back on MainActivity ..  Now  it should not be call Oncreate Method of StoreActivity when i redirect from Main Activity to Store Activity ..  Because i have already created instance of StoreActivity ..

Comment: That's not how it works. This is against the Android Framework flow. You should re-think about what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

**Start your activity like this:**

```
Intent storeIntent = new Intent(this, StoreActivity.class);
storeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(storeIntent);
```

It will call onCreate() only once on first launch of activity, if activity is already running it calls only onNewIntent() instead of create new instance of activity or calling onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible since each time you press back button, **onBackPressed()** method is called which actually destroys your **StoreActivity**.

If you want this method to not destroy your activity, just remove or comment out **super.onBackPressed()** line in this method.

In this case your activity will not be destroyed when back button is pressed, but then you will have to use any other logic to bring your **MainActivity** to top of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

try to finish the first activity after starting the new one,
add this code after the Intent command.

finish();

like that:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, newActivity.class));
finish();
```

check this link
[Finish an activity from another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379134/finish-an-activity-from-another-activity)