# Finishing all activities between MainActivity and a new activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm making an app that has a MainActivity (A) which is a navigation activity. That activity can launch an activity (B) and from there I can navigate to activity (C). Then when I navigate to activity (D) I want to finish all activities before it except MainActivity (A). So essentially if I go back from activity (A) i'll go to the same instance of activity (A).

So essentially A>B>C and then when (D) is launched the stack is A>D.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1) Use `MainActivity` as a "dispatcher". When C wants to launch D, it should do it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.putExtra("launchD", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

This code will clear all activities on top of `MainActivity`, and cause`onNewIntent()` to be called on `MainActivity`.

In `MainActivity`, override `onNewIntent()`:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent.hasExtra("launchD")) {
        // Need to launch Activity D
        Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this, D.class);
        startActivity(launchIntent);
    }
}
```

`MainActivity` will now launch D after the stack is cleared. Pressing BACK in D will return to `MainActivity`.

2) Launch D from C as usual:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, D.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

At this point, the stack is A->B->C->D

In D, override `onBackPressed()`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In this case, pressing BACK while in D will cause D, C and B to be removed from the stack and the user will return to `MainActivity`.

Note: Using the combination of flags `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` ensures that the existing instance of `MainActivity` will be reused. Android won't create a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setFlags` method to give this Intent the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`.

This will check your stack to see if an instance of `MainActivity` already exists, and if it does it'll bring that Activity to the front and clear all the Activities above it instead of restarting `MainActivity` and putting it on top of the stack.

Other way is manually calling finish() in every activity.Like :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: What if activity A isn't called MainActivity. Also for you second solution what if I don't want to close the intermediary activities until I launch activity D

Comment: You should not just hand pick several activity you want to be destroyed.Anyway try creating 'Activity' Object then calling the finish() method from another activity.Like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379134/finish-an-activity-from-another-activity)