# Closing Child Activities and Returning to the Main Activity From Further Down the Tree - Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an android project with a bunch of nested activities :-

Main --- Page 1 --- Page 2 --- Page 3

Main calls page 1.  Page 1 can call page 2 or go back to main.  Page 2 can call page 3 or go back to page 1.  Page 3 can only go back to Main.  On returning to main all the other activities have to closed, not hidden.

Now after hours of searching the usual suggestion is Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.  This doesn't do what I want though, as it seems to hide the activities, and bring Main to the front, rather than close them and leave only Main open.

Is there a way I can get Page 3 to CLOSE Page 1, 2 and 3, and leave just Main open?

Thanks

STeve

Comment: Using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` is the correct way to do this. Anything else is overkill or a hack. You must be doing something strange if it doesn't work. Can you post your pmanifest?

Comment: im afraid not.  Despite the fact the file is formatted as stack overflow requests, it wont let me upload the edit claiming it isnt formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe have a look at Broadcast Listeners: [Finish an activity from another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379134/finish-an-activity-from-another-activity#answer-10379275)

It'd probably use the least resources when you finish your page 2 when creating page 3 and at the same time broadcast to your page 1 to finish. This way you might also prevent hiccups when going back from page 3 while page 1 and 2 are finishing.

Comment: The catch is that page 2 must be able to get back to page 1 therefore finish would break that functionality

Comment: Yup, sorry, didn't see that. Updated :)