# Finish android activity from another with Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to finish an activity from another (android) with kotlin. I know the wat to do it with java is with the following code (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10379275/7280257)

at the first activity:

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcast_reciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals("finish_activity")) {
            finish();
            // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT.
        }
    }
};
registerReceiver(broadcast_reciever, new IntentFilter("finish_activity"));
```

On the other activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("finish_activity");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

For some reason converting the java activity to kotlin doesn't give a valid output, if someone could give me the correct syntax to do it properly with **kotlin** I will appreciate it

kotlin output (first activity) **[OK]**:

```
val broadcast_reciever = object : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(arg0: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val action = intent.action
        if (action == "finish_activity") {
            finish()
            // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT.
        }
    }
}
registerReceiver(broadcast_reciever, IntentFilter("finish_activity"))
```

kotlin output (2nd activity) **[OK]**

```
            val intent = Intent("finish_activity")
            sendBroadcast(intent)
```

ERROR: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJvSY.png

**FIX: THE CODE SHOWN IS RIGHT, YOU JUST NEED TO PLACE IT INSIDE THE onCreate FUNCTION**

Comment: What do you get after conversion? It would be easier to fix a specific error.

Comment: @zsmb13 question updated with the kotlin output

Comment: Can you also say what's not valid here?

Comment: @zsmb13 i've linked the error shown in the ide

Comment: This code doesn't make sens(I mean original answer) ... why? Do a simple test ... enable `Dev Options->Don't Keep Activities` check if it's work

Comment: @Selvin why it doesn't make sense...?

Comment: Obviously because you should think like there is only one instance of living Activity class at the same time

Comment: @Selvin not exacly, I'm ussing this because at first I load a login screen, then you select the login method. If the user didn't selected the login method that he wanted by accident he can always go back and select antoher method (because the login method picker is still active), but if he complete the login the two activities close.

Comment: It's not working!!! just turn on `Dev Options->Don't Keep Activities`

Comment: @Selvin it's working perfectly fine (tested)

Comment: No, it's not working , [tested](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/3599baab8dd9dbf50f283dd3bfe4fdfd) as you see on gif image the mainactivity is still there when don't keep activities is on.

Comment: so you want a video? photos? what

Comment: I did a video... And convert it to gif it's not working as you can see on gist from previous comment.

Comment: I'm not to waste more time on this because it's working perfectly, here you have the code if you want to test it by ys.

Comment: @Selvin 1st: http://i.imgur.com/vN7bThS.png 2nd: http://i.imgur.com/4sp2JSK.png (both of them are finished())

Comment: Ok, you are right, you can keep using bad code... it's not my problem...  The only right way is to use startActivityForResult and onActivityResult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `Expecting member declaration` is there because you wrote a statement (the function call) inside a class. In that scope, declarations (functions, inner classes) are expected.

You have to place your statements inside functions (and then call those from somewhere) in order for them to be executed.

Answer (score 5):

Simple code to finish a particular activity from another:

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationListner {

  class MyClass{
    companion object{
        var activity: Activity? = null
    }
  }

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    MyClass.activity = this@SplashActivity
  }


  override fun navigateFromScreen() {
    val intent = Intent(this,LoginActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
  }
}
```

Now call `SplashActivity.MyClass.activity?.finish()` from another activity to finish above activity.

Comment: You should not save activites to a variable, because this could cause a memory leak.