# Showing Loading activity until main activity is fully loaded

Tags: java, android, android-activity, loading, progressdialog

Here is the code for the main activity which is to be loaded after *onCreate* method is fully executed.

Refered [This for closing one activity from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379134/finish-an-activity-from-another-activity)

```
public class DictionarySscWords extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener 
{
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  context = this;
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(DictionarySscWords.this,LoadingIt.class);
  startActivity(myIntent);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  //all this activity work
  LoadingIt.fa.finish(); //close Loading activity
 }
}
```

Now here is the code of my loadingIt activity

```
public class LoadingIt extends AppCompatActivity {
Context context;
public static LoadingIt fa;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading_it);
    context=this;
    fa = this;
    ProgressDialog dialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading Please wait!!");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(false);
    dialog.show();
}
}
```

Problem is **LoadingIt** activity is never finished and app is stuck on Loading screen i want to finish thisactivity as the previous acivity *onCreate* method is fully executed
thanks

Comment: Have you overriden the `onFinish()` in the `LoadingIt` Activity?

Comment: Also this - You are holding a static reference to an activity. This will never go away unless you clear it manually from somewhere -> you are creating a memory leak! - From the link you have added.

Comment: Would you tell us what task you are performing in DictionarySscWords activity.

Comment: @AkshayKatariya creating a ListView using adpater

Comment: @hsm59 haven't overriden onFinish()

Comment: Can you share the logic of creating the ListView and the Adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like your solution is not really best practice. Here is what I would do:

1. Declare the `LoadingIt` activity as the startup activity
2. In the `onCreate` method, load the resources needed in the background (either with an `AsyncTask` or a `IntentService` for example)
3. Once the loading is finished, finish the `LoadingIt` activity and display the `DictionarySscWords` activity

If you post the loading logic, I could provide a sample implementation.

Comment: DictionarySscWords is not a Launcher class

Comment: What do you mean by "Launcher class", `DictionarySscWords` is an activity, right? So you can start it after the loading is finished with an intent and pass the loaded data.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Thread in onCreate() of LoadingIt class

```
public class LoadingIt extends AppCompatActivity {

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      getSupportActionBar().hide();
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading_it);

      Thread loadingThread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                super.run();
                sleep(2000);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            } finally {

                Intent main = new Intent(LoadingIt.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(main);
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    loadingThread.start();
}
```