# Log in and Sign up screens

Tags: android

I have following Activities(imagine Pinterest app):

**WellcomeActivity** with two buttons - Sign up and Log in

**LogInActivity** you come here from WellcomeActivity

**SignUpActivity** you come here from WellcomeActivity

**MainActivity** - you come here after you either logged in or signed up.

When user signed up or logged in I call `finish()` in `LogInActivity` or `SignUpActivity` and start `MainActivity`. But `WellcomeActivity` remains in the stack, so when I press Back button I'm again in `WellcomeActivity`.

I can't call `finish()` in it when I start `LogInActivity` or `SignUpActivity`, because if user decides to go back, he will exit the app.

Now, how do I design Activity transitions to have that Pinterest-like logic?

Comment: Good question the next days I'll face the same problem. I think that is slovable with a flag in the manifest to hide a activity from the activity stack

Comment: When you starting `MainActivity` in intent add this flag `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` hope it will help you

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem CLEAR_TASK, I guess. It's only available for API>11.

Comment: it is [there](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) since API 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7511896/1627802)

From WelcomeActivity, instead of startActivity(), you call startActivityForResult() when starting LoginActivity or SignupActivity.Then in the onActivityResult() of WelcomeActivity,you call finish() if resultCode is 1.

Now, when login of signup is successful, you setResult(1) in the login/signup activity, which will call onActivityResult() of WelcomeActivity with resultCode as 1 and will finish() it. If login or signup fails, you call setResult(0).

Also After setResult(1), you startActivity() to invoke MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar application.  What I did was make a Shared Preference file that had "logged in" and "sign up" as fields. When they sign up or log in, I make this value true.

In the app, when they return to the main activity, I check for onActivityResult and if they are signed up or logged in, I finish() the activity.

THis way, when they go back before log in or sign up, it doesn't close it.  I hope you understand.