# android how to kill an activity in another one?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

In an app,there are 3 activities,A,B,C. A is to log in .B is the menu,C is to set values. The working line: A->B->C. In C, there is a button named logout. When clicking logout , I setResult to B ,finish C and start A. In B,I override onActivityResult, when the resultcode is right, I finish B. But the testing data shows when A is restarted by C,B isn't be finished. Solutions are welcomed! Here is the code:

```
    Activity A: LoginActivity.java
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
            login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
            login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                     Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            LoginActivity.this.finish();
                    }
           }
    }

   Activity B: MenuActivity.java

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
            setting=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
            setting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                     Intent settingintent=new Intent(MenuActivity.this, SettingActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(settingintent,1);
                    }
           }
    }

    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode==1){
        switch(resultCode){
            case RESULT_CANCLED:
                break;
            case RESULT_OK:
                MenuActivity.this.finish();
                Log.i(TAG, "I'm killed"+System.currentTimeMillis());
                break;
        }
    }   
}
    Activity C: Setting.java
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
            logout=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
            logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                     Intent mIntent=new Intent(SettingActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
         startActivity(mIntent);
         SettingActivity.this.setResult(RESULT_OK);
         SettingActivity.this.finish();

                    }
           }
    }
```

Comment: Just `finish` the activity before starting the next one.

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivity(intent);//start the next activity
finish(); //finish the current activity
```

Found a descriptive discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511216/android-how-to-finish-an-activity-from-other-activity)

Comment: for the sake of the menu function, ActivityB cannot be finished when moving to ActivityC. In ActivityC, there is other buttons to do other work.

Answer (score 0):

Call `finish()` at the end of the `startActivity(<Your Intent>)` in `ActivityB`. Then `ActivityB` will not be in stack when moving to `ActivityC`.

Comment: for the sake of the menu function, ActivityB cannot be finished when moving to ActivityC. In ActivityC, there is other buttons to do other work.

Comment: B activity is the menu. In C , I would back to B. As a result, I can't destroy B when I move to C. Could you provide another solution? Thank you so much.

Comment: Okay. I too faced the same problem. Please add this line to your `activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`: `android:launchMode="singleTask"`

Comment: @LilySea do u find the solution??

Comment: your advice doesn't work either.I just do it as below and it works.    private ActivityB intance=null; in onCreate(), instance=this; in ActivityC, B.instance.finish().